# Using elementary row operations, can I add two rows together "simultaneously" without considering the effects of the first operation?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have the matrix A = $\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 4 & -3 \\ 2 & 5 & 5 \\ -2 & -3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, can I perform the ERO's R2 = R2 + R3 and R3 = R3 + R2 simultaneously (R3 = R3 + R2 without without considering the effects on R2 from R2 = R2 + R3)? This creates the resulting matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 4 & -3 \\ 0 & 2 & 6 \\ 0 & 2 & 6\end{bmatrix}$, which then simplifies further by R2 = R2 - R3 to be $\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 4 & -3 \\ 0 & 2 & 6 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ in echelon form.

I'm getting the same result when I don't do the simultaneous ERO's on A:

R2 = R2 + R3: $\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 4 & -3 \\ 0 & 2 & 6 \\ -2 & -3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

R3 = R3 + $\frac{2}{3}$R1: $\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 4 & -3 \\ 0 & 2 & 6 \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & -1\end{bmatrix}$

and finally R3 = R3 + $\frac{1}{6}$R2: $\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 4 & -3 \\ 0 & 2 & 6 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: It's just a nice coincidence that your original matrix had rank $2$ and the order of the rows happened to be in that way. Note that any such "simultaneous" double operations will necessarily result in two identical rows, which means the resulting matrix is rank-deficient. So if you started with a full-rank matrix, then this is never good, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. In this example, it is only the presence of row 1 that makes the results coincidentally equivalent. Imagine that you didn't have row 1, and only had the matrix
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}2 & 5 & 5 \\ -2 & -3 & 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Here, if you add the rows in the way you describe, you will turn the matrix into
$$
  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & 6\\ 0 & 2 & 6\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It's easy to see that you've changed the rank of the matrix in doing so: the resulting two rows are equal, so the rank is $1$, but in the original matrix, the rows were not multiples of each other, and the rank is $2$.

Effectively, what you're doing here is left-multiplying by the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$: each row is now the sum of the two original rows. In the $3 \times 3$ example, you were left-multiplying by the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1  & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$ These are not invertible matrices, so the row operation you're describing is not an invertible one. This is bad in various ways, depending on what the goal of your row reduction is. For example, if you're solving a system of equations, a non-invertible step may introduce extraneous solutions.